# djangrestframework to display model in foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Please excuse the title. Im not quite sure how ask this question without just showing.

In django I have two models.

```
class people(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    nickname=models.TextField(max_length=100)

class visits(models.Model):
    person=models.OneToOneField(people)
    visitdate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and then a serializer for the restapi.

```
#serializers.py

class VisitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = visits
        fields=("id","person","date")
```

When the API returns the dictionary, it looks like this.

```
{id:1,person:1,visitdate:11/23/17}
```

Is there a way to make the API return the actual values that are associated with the person with id 1? like so.

```
{id:1,person:{id:1,name:foo,nickname:bar},visitdate:11/23/17}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a serializer class for People and then add this to your visit serializer:

```
people = PeopleSerializer(read_only = True)
```

then add it(people) to fields in the Meta class, and just a suggestion, try making it a foreign key instead of a OnetoOne Relationship

Comment: Both great answers but the ForeignKey did the fix. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with nested relationship. Here is an example:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
         model = people
         fields = ('name', 'nickname')

class VisitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    person = PersonSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = visits
        fields = ("id", "person", "date")
```

Documentation on nested serializers is [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

The Corresponding Serializer would be as follows:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = people


class VisitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = visits
        fields = ('id', 'person', 'date')

    def get_person(self, obj):
        return PersonSerializer(obj.person).data
```